# Set time for daterangepicker

Tags: daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

The [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) plugin allows to set date using the setStartDate and setEndDate methods.Is there any method to set the time in the plugin.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't appear to a method to set only the time, and they don't mention it in the docs, but if you can set it using the setStartDate and setEndDate methods.

Those methods will accept a moment object, and if you are only setting date values when you call those methods, the time will default to 12:00 am. Setting a time on the moment object before passing it in will update the time in the daterangepicker. Their docs don't mention it, but the picker will update the time as well as the date if you are using the timePicker. This will also work when initializing the picker for the startDate and endDate values, as well as limiting the times for minDate and maxDate.

Note that if you set a maxDate without a defined time, it will default to 12:00 am which can cause issues if you're using the timePicker. For example, if I set a maxDate of 04/04/2017, the picker will let me choose that date, but it will not let me select a time on 04/04/2017 past 12:00am. To fix this, I used the moment library to set .hour(23) and .minutes(59) on the moment object I wanted to set the maxDate to. This allows users to select any hour or minute on 04/04/2017. The docs for setting times on moments can be found here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

It's not exactly what you asked but I'll provide the solution I used to get around a similar issue for changing values that don't have methods here in case anyone else needs it. I needed to dynamically change the maxDate, but there isn't a built in method to change it, only an option to set it when initializing the picker. In order to work around it, I removed the date range picker and reinitialized it on the same input with the updated options. If you need to remove the picker, the use:

```
$('#myInput').data('daterangepicker').remove();
```