# daterangepicker startDate not returning same value (or, how to set the initial time with daterangepicker?)

Tags: daterangepicker

I have a time-only daterangepicker that I want to set the initial time value for. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152904/set-time-for-daterangepicker) that talks about using startDate to set the time (undocumented feature). But when I set the time, and then get the time, it's off by 10 hours. Almost certainly a time zone issue but I don't know how to fix or workaround.

```
var dateNotUsed = '2020-01-01'; /* can be any valid date; not shown to user */
var startTime = '10:15 am';

$('#myTimePicker').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        singleDatePicker: true,
        startDate: '"' + dateNotUsed + " " + startTime + '"',
        timePickerIncrement: 1,
        locale: {
            format: 'hh:mm a'
        }
    }).on('show.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        picker.container.find(".calendar-table").hide();
});

var getTime = $('#myTimePicker').val();
```

At this point getTime == '08:15 pm', not the 10:15am value we tried to set. The control displays '08:15 pm' to the user, instead of '10:15am'.

I could have my program do a test when it starts up to calculate the offset daterangepicker using, and then use the negative of that offset whenever I want to set the time. Was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the time zone issue (if that's what it was; might have just been badly formed data) works if you use moment() to set the startDate:

`startDate: moment(startTime),`

where startTime is in this format:

`var startTime = '03:25:00'; // 3:25am`